# PhpStorm + VueJS

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm

Как заставить PhpStorm ставить табы в .vue файлах как 4 пробела в блоках template и style, но 2 пробела в script?

Плагин для Vue.js установлен, файлы *.vue относятся к типу "Vue.js Template", в настройках Code Style для JavaScript задано 2 пробела.

Comment: в phpStrom вроде у плагинов даже настроек нет, только у встроенных :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Ctrl+Alt+S (File→Settings)
2. Editor→Code Style→HTML (название вашего языка)
3. Необходимо изменить Tab size, Ident, Continuation ident — я ставлю все 2.
4. Если пользуетесь пробелами, а не табами необходимо снять галочку Use tab character (я снял).
5. В окне редактирования файла нажать Ctrl+Alt+L (Code→Reformat Code)
6. Если всё равно после Ctrl+Alt+L (Code→Reformat Code) ставит пробелы, попробуйте снять галочку с Enable EditorConfig support (File→Settings→Editor→Code Style)

Более детально в официальной документации

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm

Answer (score 0):

В **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Tabs and Indents**, установите **Indent** = *2*, в **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Tabs and Indents** и **Settings | Editor | Code Style | CSS | Tabs and Indents** - *4*.

Comment: именно так всё и настроено, но это, к сожалению, не работает(

Comment: должно работать. Попробуйте отключить поддержку `.editorconfig` (**Settings | Editor | Code Style, Enable Editorconfig support**) - настройки в `.editorconfig` по умолчанию имеют приоритет перед настройками IDE

Comment: такой настройки нет https://ibb.co/e4zkde как и .editorconfig файла https://ibb.co/k1ubJe